# Create a lower triangular matrix from a given vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

My problem is the following: I have a vector as

> [3,4,5,6,7]

I want to create a matrix as

```
3 0 0 0 0   
3 4 0 0 0   
3 4 5 0 0   
3 4 5 6 0   
3 4 5 6 7
```

However, I don't want to use for loops because of the problem of size that I will eventually get.
I was thinking about using `flipud`, `fliprl`, `hankel` and `toeplitz` functions but cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = [3,4,5,6,7]
tril(ones(length(x),1)*x)

ans =

 3     0     0     0     0
 3     4     0     0     0
 3     4     5     0     0
 3     4     5     6     0
 3     4     5     6     7
```

Comment: Well, I found out another way based on Diego's answer:

 tril(repmat(A, length(A),1)) but your's is also correct! thanks

Answer (score 1):

If A is your vector, you can do

M=repmat(A, length(A), 1) .* tril(ones(length(A),length(A)),0)

Comment: This is almost perfectly working except that we need to change the -1 to 0. I mean the working version is : repmat(A, length(A), 1) .* tril(ones(length(A),length(A)),0) many thanksssss